Issues with RX 7600 GPU not working in Blender on Ubuntu
I am a beginner with Ubuntu. I have an RX 7600 graphics card, but it doesn't work in Blender. It shows up in the drivers, but not in Blender.

I downloaded the drivers from the official website, but reinstalling them doesn't help. I also updated all libraries I found related to this issue, but it didn't work. What should I do? Here's the crash log for Blender. Has anyone experienced this?

You've given no clues as to Ubuntu product & release; and mention a crash log but none has been provided (no link or whatever was intended).
